# ServletContext getResource not working

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to use `ServletContext.getResource` to retrieve a `java.net.url` reference to an image file (which I will then include in a PDF library using iText).
When I use `ServletContext.getRealPath("picture.jpg")`, I get back a string URL. However, getResource always returns `null`.

**Example 1**:

```
String picture = ServletContext.getRealPath("picture.jpg");
// picture contains a non-null String with the correct path
URL pictureURL = ServletContext.getResource(picture);
// pictureURL is always null
```

**Example 2**:

```
URL pictureURL = ServletContext.getResource("picture.jpg");
// pictureURL is always null
```

So what is the correct way to build a java.net.URL object pointing to a file in my `webapps/` folder? Why does `getRealPath` work but not `getResource`?

In case it helps at all, here is my folder structure

```
webapps -> mySite -> picture.jpg
```

Does my picture need to be stored in either `WEB-INF` or `WEB-INF/classes` to be read by `getResource`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Returns a URL to the resource that is mapped to a specified path. The path must begin with a "/" and is interpreted as relative to the current context root.

So you must provide the context-relative full path. For example:

```
URL pictureURL = servletContext.getResource("/images/picture.jpg");
```

(note the lower-cased `servletContext` variable)

Comment: adding the leading slash fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

`getRealPath()` provides the operating specific absolute path of a resource, while `getResource()` accepts a path relative to the context directory, and the parameter must begin with a "/".   Try `ServletContext.getResource ("/picture.jpg")` instead.

Doc:
[getResource](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource(java.lang.String))